# What does this function notation mean?

Tags: notation

My text tells me that the general term of a sequence can be looked at like a function:

$
f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$

What does that mean translated into common english?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics). In this case, $\mathbf{N}$ is the domain, while $\mathbf{R}$ is the codomain.

Answer (score 2):

This specific case is called a *sequence*. The function $f$ takes in an input from the natural numbers (denoted $\mathbb N$), and gives an output in the real numbers (denoted $\mathbb R$).

In general, this notation contains three parts: the function name, the domain, and the codomain. The function name (in your case $f$) is the same $f$ appearing in the notation $f(x)$. The domain is the set of inputs to your function (in your case the natural numbers $\mathbb N$). The *codomain* is the set of possible outputs that the function can give (in your case the real number $\mathbb R$).

Comment: In high school I learned about the range of the function. How is that related to the codomain?

Comment: The range will typically be a subset of the codomain. The elements of the range are the values that *are* mapped to. For instance, you could define $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f(x) = 12$. The codomain of your function is $\mathbb R$, but the range is just $\{12\}$.

Comment: Ah I see, so the codomain is the family of numbers that the range belongs to?

Comment: Exactly!${}{}{}$